# How to order a matrix by the numeric or alphabetic values of the column vectors in R?

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

The title with the following example should be self-explanatory:

```
m = unique(replicate(5, sample(1:5, 5, rep=F)), MARGIN = 2)
m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    1    4    3
[2,]    5    1    5    1    2
[3,]    4    3    3    3    1
[4,]    3    4    4    5    5
[5,]    2    2    2    2    4
```

But what I want is instead:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    3    4    5
[2,]    5    5    2    1    1
[3,]    3    4    1    3    3
[4,]    4    3    5    5    4
[5,]    2    2    4    2    2
```

Ideally, I would like to find a method that allows the same process to be carried out when the column vectors are words (alphabetic order).

I tried things like `m[ , sort(m)]` but nothing did the trick...

Comment: So you just want to sort by the first row?

Comment: So, you want the columns ordered by the first row values, using as tie-breaker 2nd row values, 3rd row values, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m[, order(m[1, ])` will order the columns by the first row. `m[, order(m[1, ], m[2, ])]` will order by the first row, using second row as tie-breaker. Getting fancy, `m[, do.call(order, split(m, row(m)))]` will order the columns by the first row, using all subsequent rows for tie-breakers. This will work `character` data just as well as `numeric`.

```
set.seed(47)
m = replicate(5, sample(1:5, 5, rep=F))
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    5    4    1    5    1
# [2,]    2    2    3    2    3
# [3,]    3    5    5    1    2
# [4,]    4    3    2    3    5
# [5,]    1    1    4    4    4
m[, do.call(order, split(m, row(m)))]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    1    4    5    5
# [2,]    3    3    2    2    2
# [3,]    2    5    5    1    3
# [4,]    5    2    3    3    4
# [5,]    4    4    1    4    1
```

Comment: Great! It works. Can you please adjust with the minor change in the OP code?

Comment: Yes, just for concordance between OP and answer. I know it makes no difference as to the answer itself.

Comment: When simulating data, it's best to `set.seed()` so it is reproducible. I got rid of the `unique()` because it isn't doing anything. I'd suggest copying my updated code (including the `set.seed()` to the question for concordance -- setting seed means even the random values will be reproducible and match in both question and answer.